# How much repetition of a word or phrase is too much?

Tags: style, creative-writing

I like to experiment with rhetorical devices to add spice in my writing. Repetition can be used for emphasis, establishing rhythm, etc.

For example:

> **Over and over again**, my mind jumps between her ghoulish presence on the night she lured me into the woods, near-human behavior when she tried to justify her barbarism, and blood-stained figure after she mutilated the people who were once my friends. **Over and over again**, I'm plagued by the fright she put into me, pity she'd led me to have for her, and rage she put into me. **Over and over again**, I see the faces of my neighbors and friends, previously residents of the small town I'd grown up surrounded by, now victims of Adaneene and her father's hunger. **Over and over again**, I see their bodies, the way the monster and her father had left them after their horrifying last moments that the monster couldn't care enough to spare them from. **Over and over again**, I see myself **not able to save** them, and see myself in the future **not able to save** anyone.

This passage alone not only repeats "over and over again" five times and "not able to save" twice, but it also uses parallelism.

Is this excessive repetition? What's a way to determine whether or not repetition, used as a literary or rhetorical device, is too much for the readers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read it out loud, or have somebody read it to you.  Part of it is personal preference, but as a reader and listener, I've noticed that edited speeches or novels will not usually have more than 1-2 repetitions (after the first occurrence of the phrase).  On the other hand, if you are at a critical point in your book - the end of a part, or the end of the novel - it might be more generally acceptable to have more repetition.

Emphasis on the word "general" - there are no rules in creative writing, only opinions.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question. I normally don't use that much, but this passage takes place after a key plot point, one that strongly troubles the narrator.